# Sort html radio buttons according to the attribute 'name'

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sorting, radio-button

```
<input type="radio" name="AIM Data Quality Report" value="1" ng-click="DisplayMonthYear()" />
AIM Data Quality Report
<br />
<input type="radio" name="Compliance Report" value="14" ng-click="DisplayYear()" />Compliance Projects Report
<br />
<input type="radio" name="AIM Detailed Report" value="2" ng-click="DisplayMonthYear()" />AIM Detailed Report
<br />
```

The output should be radiobuttons in this order.

AIM Data Quality Report
AIM Detailed Report
Compliance Report

Comment: Simply change the sequence in `view`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L8pXL/59/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to keep the values of the radio inputs in an array in the controller and then use ng-repeat to output them and orderby to sort the values:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="input in radioInputs | orderBy:'name'">
        <input type="radio" name="{{input.name}}" value="{{input.value}}" ng-click="{{input.functionOnClick}}" />{{input.name}}
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.radioInputs = [
        {id: 0, name: 'AIM Data Quality Report', value: "1", functionOnClick: "DisplayMonthYear()"},
        {id: 1, name: 'Compliance Report', value: "14", functionOnClick: "DisplayYear()"},
        {id: 2, name: 'AIM Detailed Report', value: "2", functionOnClick: "DisplayMonthYear()"}
];

}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fsalin/u750fw7u/1/